# Shiledui export to pdf

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, shieldui

I try to export file ie. html to pdf 
now i try to populate html table through jquery and webstatic method

data is successfully  display in table now when i try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $("#pdf").click(function () {
            // parse the HTML table element having an id=exportTable
            var dataSource = shield.DataSource.create({
                data: "#tabledata",
                schema: {
                    type: "table",
                    fields: {
                        ID: { type: String },
                        Owner: { type: Number },
                        RegNo: { type: String }
                    }
                }
            });

            // when parsing is done, export the data to PDF
            dataSource.read().then(function (data) {
                var pdf = new shield.exp.PDFDocument({
                    author: "PrepBootstrap",
                    created: new Date()
                });

                pdf.addPage("a4", "portrait");

                pdf.table(
                    50,
                    50,
                    data,
                    [
                        { field: "ID", title: "ID", width: 100 },
                        { field: "Owner", title: "Owner", width: 10 },
                        { field: "RegNo", title: "RegNo", width: 100 }

                    ],
                    {
                        margins: {
                            top: 50,
                            left: 50
                        }
                    }
                );

                pdf.saveAs({
                    fileName: "PrepBootstrapPDF"
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

PDF is download and i successfully export to PDF file now i want to put **image on PDF and title in PDF how i do this**

Answer (score 1):

This is custom functionality, not supported out of the box, as far as I know.

You should be able to talk with Shield UI's support and let them know that you want this functionality implemented for you.

Answer (score 0):

pdf.text("Your text here", 30, 50, 0, 50);

I have not found much documentation like with FPDF (which is well documented). So the best I have figured out so far parameters are like this 
pdf.text(Your text, left-margin, ???, Rotate text, top-margin).

I am not a pro with this and am stumbling through it the best I can.

One last thing, the table you have has 2 parameters in the beginning, 50,50, then the table itself.

2nd parameter is the top margin.

I'm not sure if this helps and it could be a little late. But it's what I have found so far